# Use python to turn mysql into json

Tags: python, mysql, json

I want to use python to turn mysql into json, but when I use the following code, the result is json line by line, not a whole set of json

```
import pymysql
import json
sql="**"

conn=pymysql.connect(host='localhost',user='root',passwd="abc",db="mydatabase",port=123) 
cur=conn.cursor() 
cur.execute(sql)
data=cur.fetchall()

fields=cur.description
cur.close () 
conn.close()

column_list = []
for i in fields:
    column_list.append(i[0])

for row in data:
    result = {}
    result[column_list[0]] = row[0]
    result[column_list[1]] = row[1]
    result[column_list[2]] = str(row[2])
    result[column_list[3]] = row[3]

    j=json.dumps(result)
    print(j)
```

Comment: Don't `dump` every row in the loop; `append` each row to a `list`, then `dump` the entire list after the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pull out the `json.dumps()` line from the for loop. This is resulting in conversion of into json with each iteration and printing in each iteration.

Your code should look like this :

```
import pymysql
import json
sql="**"

conn=pymysql.connect(host='localhost',user='root',passwd="abc",db="mydatabase",port=123) 
cur=conn.cursor() 
cur.execute(sql)
data=cur.fetchall()

fields=cur.description
cur.close () 
conn.close()

column_list = []
for i in fields:
    column_list.append(i[0])
final_resultset = []
for row in data:
    result = {}
    result[column_list[0]] = row[0]
    result[column_list[1]] = row[1]
    result[column_list[2]] = str(row[2])
    result[column_list[3]] = row[3]

    final_resultset.append(result)

j=json.dumps(final_resultset)
print(j)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below

```
   cur.execute('''SELECT * FROM Users WHERE id=1''')
   row_headers=[x[0] for x in cur.description] #this will extract row headers
   rv = cur.fetchall()
   json_data=[]
   for result in rv:
        json_data.append(dict(zip(row_headers,result)))
   j=json.dumps(json_data)
   print(j)
```